# UI Hide Sensitive Data like SSN or Tax Ids and display only on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying the below approach:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.TaxId )
<input type="button" id="togglePasswordField" value="Toggle Password" onclick="togglePasswordFieldClicked();" />


$(document).on("ready", function () {
    var sensitiveField = document.getElementById('TaxId');
        sensitiveField.type = 'password';
        sensitiveField.value='@Model.TaxId';
});

function togglePasswordFieldClicked() {
    var sensitiveField = document.getElementById('TaxId');
    var value = sensitiveField .value;
    if (sensitiveField .type == 'password') {
        sensitiveField .type = 'text';
    } else {
        sensitiveField .type = 'password';
    }
    sensitiveField .value = value;
}
```

Requirements:

1. On page load the taxid value should be hidden
2. When users clicks a button taxid value must be shown / hidden ( toggle functionality)

3.The original value must be saved.

Issue with my approach:

Value is saved in the db but not displayed correctly in the ui ( model binding not happening )

If PasswordFor doesnt retain a value on client side , Is there any other approach I can follow to get this working ?

Comment: `PasswordFor()` do not show a value when initially displayed (in fact its the only `HtmlHelper` method that does not, and its a security measure). What is the purpose of 'hiding' it - its a `type="password"` so it only displays dots in place of characters when the user enters a value anyway?

Comment: Its a taxid field that needs to be shown/hidden based on button click , the only reason I used a PasswordFor is to dispaly dots and yet retain the original value.  Is there any other way we can hide/show values and still save the original values??

Comment: Then just use `TextBoxFor()` and your script simply needs to be `$('#togglePasswordField').click(function() { $('#yourTextBoxId').toggle(); })` (and remove `onclick="togglePasswordFieldClicked()`). But why you would want to do show/hide the value is completely unclear

Comment: Thats how the users want ... They want to see the tax id on button click or hide when they dont want to see.